# In Xcode how can I detect what phase number I am in via the shell?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I am using cocoapods which automatically adds build phases to my project. I have a build phase which I would like to be the LAST build phase, no matter what (It's a verification phase). Is there a way to determine the phase number from a variable in the shell script? Is there any meta information I can examine that would tell me if there are more phases to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options, both use [Xcodeproj](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj).

You could use Xcodeproj in your build phase to open up your Xcodeproject and look through the target's build phases. I wouldn't recommend this, as it's slow to open your xcodeproj for inspection, and on your normal build cycle.

Or you could have a `post_install` [hook](https://github.com/artsy/eigen/blob/a3479a6c4a83bd84f1dab2112b3423cacb20f709/Podfile#L120-L136) in your Podfile that does the build phase validation, which will happen occasionally, but not on every build.

Comment: Awesome. Sounds perfect! Like that xcodeproj project!